# SQL CASE WHEN bigger than

Tags: sql, case

I've been searching a lot and in the examples everything looks fine, but in fact it doesn't.
I want to calculate the salary increase dependently on the amount. Missing keyword error appears.

```
SELECT o.operator_name,
       o.salary,
(CASE o.salary
 WHEN o.salary < 500 THEN o.salary * 1.35
 WHEN o.salary >= 500 AND o.salary < 1000 THEN o.salary * 1.15
 WHEN o.salary >= 1000 AND o.salary < 1500 THEN o.salary * 1.05 
 END) AS "Increase"
FROM operators o;
```

I tried with IF ELSIF, I got "FROM is not where is expected".

Comment: Change `CASE o.salary WHEN ...` to `CASE WHEN ...`

Comment: You don't need the `>=` tests. The tests are performed sequentially, so if it's `< 500`, the first `WHEN` will be matched and it will never get to the second one.

Answer (score 7):

You've mixed two formats of `CASE`, try:

```
SELECT o.operator_name,
       o.salary,
       CASE WHEN o.salary < 500 THEN o.salary * 1.35
            WHEN o.salary >= 500 AND o.salary < 1000 THEN o.salary * 1.15
            WHEN o.salary >= 1000 AND o.salary < 1500 THEN o.salary * 1.05 
            ELSE o.salary
       END AS "Increase"
FROM operators o;
```

This format allows for multiple/disparate fields to be used as well as comparison operators.  You may also be needing an `ELSE` before the `END` if you want something to be returned for salary values 1500 and over.

It's also worth noting that `CASE` exits at the first met criteria, so you could use:

```
SELECT o.operator_name,
       o.salary,
       CASE WHEN o.salary < 500 THEN o.salary * 1.35
            WHEN o.salary < 1000 THEN o.salary * 1.15
            WHEN o.salary < 1500 THEN o.salary * 1.05 
            ELSE o.salary
       END AS "Increase"
FROM operators o;
```

The other format of `CASE` wouldn't work for your example, but here's a simple example to show usage:

```
SELECT CASE col1 
           WHEN 'cat' THEN 1  
           WHEN 'dog' THEN 2 
       END
FROM table1
```

That is equivalent to:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN col1 = 'cat' THEN 1 
            WHEN col1 = 'dog' THEN 2 
       END
FROM table1
```

Comment: Are you really allowed to put comparison operators in the second form? I thought it was only for equality tests, e.g. `WHEN 500 THEN ...`

Comment: @Barmar wasn't even thinking about that, pretty sure you're correct.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was that 'o.salary' after 'CASE'.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want ELSE:

```
SELECT o.operator_name,
       o.salary,
(CASE 
 WHEN o.salary < 500 THEN o.salary * 1.35
 WHEN o.salary >= 500 AND o.salary < 1000 THEN o.salary * 1.15
 WHEN o.salary >= 1000 AND o.salary < 1500 THEN o.salary * 1.05 
ELSE o.salary
 END) AS "Increase"
FROM operators o;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT o.operator_name, 
       o.salary, 
       CASE 
         WHEN o.salary < 500 THEN o.salary * 1.35 
         WHEN o.salary >= 500 
              AND o.salary < 1000 THEN o.salary * 1.15 
         WHEN o.salary >= 1000 
              AND o.salary < 1500 THEN o.salary * 1.05 
       END AS "Increase" 
FROM   operators o;
```

Should do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the default case. You have to finish your case with an 'ELSE default_value'. So :

```
CASE foo
  WHEN bar THEN 1
  WHEN baz THEN 2
  ELSE 0
END
```